# How to bind Double parameter with Play 2.0 routing

Tags: java, parameters, routes, double, playframework-2.0

I'm learning myself Play 2.0 (Java API used) and would like to have a double/float parameter (for location coordinates), something like http://myfooapp.com/events/find?latitude=25.123456&longitude=60.251253.

I can do this by getting the parameters as String and parsing them at controller etc but can I use automatic binding here?

Now, I first tried simply having one double value:

```
GET     /events/foo                 controllers.Application.foo(doublevalue: Double)
```

with

```
public static Result foo(Double doublevalue) {
    return ok(index.render("Foo:" + doublevalue));
}
```

What I got was *"No QueryString binder found for type Double. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type."*

Have I missed something already provided or
do I have to make a custom QueryStringBindable that parses Double?

I found some instructions on making a custom string query string binder with Scala at http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2012/04/09/how-to-implement-a-custom-pathbindable-with-play-2/

### What I tried:

I implemented DoubleBinder at package binders:

```
import java.util.Map;
import play.libs.F.Option;
import play.mvc.QueryStringBindable;

public class DoubleBinder implements QueryStringBindable<Double>{

    @Override
    public Option<Double> bind(String key, Map<String, String[]> data) {
        String[] value = data.get(key);
        if(value == null || value.length == 0) {
            return Option.None();
        } else {
            return Option.Some(Double.parseDouble(value[0]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String javascriptUnbind() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String unbind(String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

And tried to add it to project/Build.scala's main:

```
routesImport += "binders._"
```

but same result : "No QueryString binder found for type Double...."

- I also changed the routing signature to java.lang.Double but that didn't help either
- I also changed the DoubleBinder to implement play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable (instead of  play.mvc.QueryStringBindable) both with Double & java.lang.Double at the routing signature but no help still

Comment: I think that’s a bug in the support of Java `QueryStringBindable`. Please file a ticket in the [tracker](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/overview). BTW, `Double` and `Float` should be supported out of the box in Play 2.1.

Comment: There seems to be a pull request for it on github https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/235

Comment: Ok, I found the problem source and a solution. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently (in Play 2.0), Java binders only work with self-recursive types. That is, types looking like the following:

```java
class Foo extends QueryStringBindable<Foo> {
  …
}
```

So, if you want to define a binder for `java.lang.Double`, which is an existing type of Java, you need to wrap it in a self-recursive type. For example:

```java
package util;

public class DoubleW implements QueryStringBindable<DoubleW> {

    public Double value = null;

    @Override
    public Option<DoubleW> bind(String key, Map<String, String[]> data) {
        String[] vs = data.get(key);
        if (vs != null && vs.length > 0) {
            String v = vs[0];
            value = Double.parseDouble(v);
            return F.Some(this);
        }
        return F.None();
    }

    @Override
    public String unbind(String key) {
        return key + "=" + value;
    }

    @Override
    public String javascriptUnbind() {
         return value.toString();
    }

}
```

Then you can use it as follows in your application:

```
GET    /foo     controllers.Application.action(d: util.DoubleW)
```

```java
public static Result action(DoubleW d) {
      …
}
```

Comment: OK, I got this to works, thanks! Pity that binding doesn't work for standard types, hope to get this better with Play 2.1?

Comment: Sure, standard types support will be built-in in Play 2.1. See [this pull request](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/261)

Comment: Is this fixed in 2.1 for non-standard types or do we still need a wrapper to create self-recursive types?

Comment: The self-recursive type is still needed

Comment: I am currently having the same issue as original poster in my project. I am unsure if I should just use 2.1.0 because I don't want other conflicts to arise. Where exactly would you store this DoubleW class in order to use it? Will I need to create a separate util package in my project?

Comment: You can put the `DoubleW` class in whatever package you want, in your project. The point is that you have to fully qualify it in your routes definitions (unless you use the `routesImport` trick in your build file).

Comment: Ok, I did this and then imported it in my controller application and model class. I modified the attributes I already had in place so that they would be DoubleW type instead of double. Are there any additional steps I am missing? Because the DoubleW as is in my project is not compatible with the double type and I unable to perform any arithmetic operations on it.

Comment: The `DoubleW` class should only live in your controllers. You can provide your models a `double` value from a `DoubleW` value.