# play 2.1-rc2 java: handling javascript routes with fixed null parameters

Tags: java, javascript, scala, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2.1-RC2 and I have a couple of routes that look something like:

```
POST  /resource                 SomeController.action(parent = null)
POST  /parent/:parent/resource  SomeController.action(parent: String)
```

Assuming I have exported these routes to javascript as `jsRoutes` using the `play.Routes.javascriptRouter` method, I would like to call either `jsRoutes.SomeController.action()` or `jsRoutes.SomeController.action("some-id")` and get the appropriate route. However, this is the javascript function I get:

```js
function (parent) {
    if (parent == "null") {
        return _wA({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/" + "resource"
        })
    }
    if (true) {
        return _wA({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/" + "parent/" + (function (k, v) {
                return v
            })("parent", parent) + "/resource"
        })
    }
}
```

It seems that Play's `String` path binder has converted the fixed `null` value to the javascript `String` literal `"null"`.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286725/how-to-bind-double-parameter-with-play-2-0-routing) and [this code file](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/PathBindable.java), but I couldn't really find what I was looking for. I don't want to have to use a mostly-redundant wrapper for the `String` class. You'd think this would be supported out of the box. Is this a limitation of the framework or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of the framework. I ended up passing `"null"` to the javascript function whenever I needed to access the first route. Ugly, but works until the issue is fixed.