# No QueryString binder found for type Double. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

So I am using play 2.0 and I am trying to pass doubles from my view back to controller application and I get this error: *No QueryString binder found for type Double. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type*. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286725/how-to-bind-double-parameter-with-play-2-0-routing) thread and see that java binders only work with self-recursive types in play 2.0 but they will be supported in play 2.1. Unfortunately I am not in a position to migrate my project to 2.1 so I tried to follow the answer to the question linked. I created a util package in my project and inside it is the DoubleW class:

```
package util;

import java.util.Map;

import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.F.Option;
import play.mvc.QueryStringBindable;

public class DoubleW implements QueryStringBindable<DoubleW> {

    public Double value = null;

    @Override
    public Option<DoubleW> bind(String key, Map<String, String[]> data) {
        String[] vs = data.get(key);
        if (vs != null && vs.length > 0) {
            String v = vs[0];
            value = Double.parseDouble(v);
            return F.Some(this);
        }
        return F.None();
    }

    @Override
    public String unbind(String key) {
        return key + "=" + value;
    }

    @Override
    public String javascriptUnbind() {
         return value.toString();
    }

}
```

I imported this where it was needed in the controller/application and one of the model classes where I need to use doubles. I replaced the double data types with the new DoubleW in the application and model methods concerned. Finally I modified my routing table so it would expect the new parameters:

*GET     /findMatch                         controllers.Application.matcher(sLat: util.DoubleW, sLon: util.DoubleW, eLat: util.DoubleW, eLon: util.DoubleW)*

Inside the model method which the Application matcher method uses I need to perform arithmetic. However when I run my project I get this error: *error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='*. It seems this new type to handle doubles (DoubleW) is regarded as a string, I cannot perform arithmetic on it and I can not assign a standard java double its value. I am not sure if I have missed a step in the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286725/how-to-bind-double-parameter-with-play-2-0-routing) but I am rather lost on what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Play 2.0 I found the easiest solution was to use Scala - even in a Java project (I explained this in one of [my Play Basics blog posts](http://www.mariussoutier.com/blog/2012/12/11/playframework-routes-part-2-advanced/).

If you don't know Scala, just paste the following in a file called `Binders.scala` and add `routesImport += "util.Binders._"` to your `Build.scala`.

```
package util

object Binders {

  implicit object DoubleQueryBindable extends QueryStringBindable[Double] {
    def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]) = params.get(key).flatMap(_.headOption).map { value =>
      try {
        Right(value.toDouble)
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>  Left("Cannot parse parameter " + key + " as Double")
      }
    }
    def unbind(key: String, value: Double) = key + "=" + value.toString
  }

  implicit object DoublePathBindable extends PathBindable[Double] {
    def bind(key: String, value: String) = try {
      Right(value.toDouble)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => Left("Cannot parse parameter '" + key + "' as Double")
    }

    def unbind(key: String, value: Double): String = value.toString
  }
}
```